# Call opengl function on resize

Tags: opengl, resize, glfw

I want to call an openGL function on resize to make the game responsive.

I have this function:

```
void Game::changeSize(int w, int h) {

    if (h == 0)
        h = 1;

    float ratio =  w * 1.0 / h;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    gluPerspective(45.0f, ratio, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

I call it in the mainloop with changeSize(m_width, m_height).
It sets the viewport, but on framebuffer_size_callback GLFW I can't set the new width and height.

```
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    Game game;
    game.changeSize(width, height);
}
```

How to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating a new `Game` instance in the callback? Is that some form of singleton class?

Comment: To use the void in another class.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting a integer on 0 to execute the function if it hasn't been resized yet.

So for example,

```
int resize = 0;

if(resize == 0){
game.changeResize(window, m_width, m_height);
}

//in the resize callback function
resize = 1;

game.changeResize(window, width, height);
```